# Is there a way to choose a random button using nana library?

Tags: c++, random, nana

So i just started using *nana c++* library. I made some buttons and i need to find a function or something that choose a random button from those i created. Is there anyway i can do that?
Ps: i'm using *code::blocks*

Comment: How do you store the buttons, as distinct objects or using a vector or other container? If you use a container then you could [generate a random number in the range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) of `0` to `container.size()`.

Comment: I stored them as distinct objects for now, i will try with a vector :D The main problem is i need a solution to focus / highlight one random button :-?

Comment: If you have distinct objects, you can still make a container of pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real reason to use an extra library for the random part; the C++ standard library has the functionality already. See `<random>`; you'd probably want a `std::uniform_int_distribution`. This assumes you've got your buttons numbered; else just stuff a pointer to each button in a `std::vector<Button*>`.

One tip: unlike almost all C++ functions, `std::uniform_int_distribution` will generate numbers up to **and including** `std::uniform_int_distribution::max`.